# scrollbarBlock changes his class after the transition to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, slider

I have iosSlider in my website. Here settings which I use in it:

```
$('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
  //autoSlide: true,
  desktopClickDrag: true,
  snapToChildren: true,
  scrollbarDrag: true,
  scrollbarContainer: '.iosSlider',
  scrollbarMargin: 0,
  scrollbarHeight: '10px',
  scrollbarBorderRadius: 1,
  scrollbarOpacity: 1
});

// this part is setting initial position to scrollbar block(before it animation)
var x = $('#home-wrap').height() + 10;
$('.scrollbarBlock1').css( 'top', x + 'px' );

// this part animating scrollbar after appearance of logo
var z = $('#home-wrap').height() - 70; 
$('.scrollbarBlock1').animate({top: z + 'px' },500);
```

So, I have some strange thing, when you come to [home page](http://beardhouse.com.ua/#/) - all work's as it need, the scroolbar placed where i want
[image]

but if you go to any other page 'about us'(О НАС), 'catalog'(КАТАЛОГ) or something else and then will return to home page(ГЛАВНАЯ) - the scroolbar will change his class and therefore my styles which I set to it doesn't work[image]

What a heck is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var $ele = $(".iosSlider").children().eq(1);
// this part is setting initial position to scrollbar block(before it animation)
 var x = $('#home-wrap').height() + 10;
 $ele.css( 'top', x + 'px' );

  // this part animating scrollbar after appearance of logo
var z = $('#home-wrap').height() - 70; 
$ele.animate({top: z + 'px' },500);
```

Comment: when I return to home page - it still replaced by .scrollbarBlock2